# PATH struggling

Tags: java, windows

simple question. I got JDK 1.7 and 1.8 on my pc (Windows). I need both them. I got a "%JAVA_HOME%\bin;" entry in my PATH (JAVA_HOME=path_to_my_jdk_1_7). By command line I change the JAVA_HOME value like this:

```
set JAVA_HOME=path_to_my_jdk_1_8
```

Now if I type

```
C:\Users\Francesco>java -version
java version "1.8.0_20"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_20-b26)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.20-b23, mixed mode)
```

but when I type

```
C:\Users\Francesco>javac -version
javac 1.7.0_45
```

Why javac is still 1.7?

Comment: At a guess, because the earlier JAVA_HOME\bin value is already in the PATH and appears first.

Comment: Is the path evaluated dynamically under Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run `set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;` again after setting the JAVA_HOME variable to 1.8 JAVA_HOME.